# How to remove Ubuntu 20.04 boot animation?

Tags: boot, 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and want to remove boot animation so then I can see the programs that are loaded into the system when it boots up.

What I want is to see the below screen. Not the Ubuntu logo.

[image]

Comment: Removing Plymouth pakage might do the job..

Comment: The quiet splash setting in grub shows the logo. I found changing quiet splash to "noplymouth" also seems to speed up boot. Try once manually changing in grub menu with e and replace on linux line. If that works as expected then you can make permanent with edit to `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and remove the string `quiet splash` from the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Example for one of my pc's:

Before: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash stack_guard_gap=1"`

After: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="stack_guard_gap=1"`

Comment: As far as I know, specifically, the `quiet` option suppresses the readouts that OP is after (but does not provide anything in place of it), while the `splash` is providing some kind of "user friendly" visual to at least show something while the system works on booting. That's how removing both leads to the desired result.

Comment: @Levente thanks! I learned something, I always thought "quiet splash" was one option!

Answer (score 0):

### Toggling to Traditional Text-based Boot

If you want to see the text-based boot messages (which use the Plymouth "details" plugin, press the `ESCAPE` key at any point when Plymouth is running. Note that the `ESCAPE` key acts as a toggle, so you can keep switching between graphical and text mode as required.

To show debug messages, you need to enter grub menu and remove `quiet` from options. You can permanently remove `quiet` from following line in `/etc/default/grub`, save and `sudo grub-update`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet resume=UUID=YOUR_SWAP_UUID"
```

This way you won't have to remove the boot animation permanently

### Permanently set to Traditional Text-based Boot

To have the boot start in "text mode" permanently,
open `/etc/default/grub` as sudo and change the following line. Replace `splash quiet` with `noplymouth`, save file and run `sudo grub-update`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet resume=UUID=YOUR_SWAP_UUID"
```

Of course run `sudo update-grub` every time you change this file `/etc/default/grub`.

Ref: [Debugging Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Debugging)